# pass async results from parent to child component react functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rxjs, react-hooks, react-router

I have a functional component that designed to search tasks and show in a task resultbox, the async Task data is set via useState hook and passed to the child component "TaskResultBox". The state is not changed and values are not rendered into the child component. I have verified the values retrieved from API using debug. but not re-rendering the data in the child component.

```
import React from 'react'
import {useState} from 'react'


function SearchTask({onAddTask}) {
    const [searchInputValue, setSearchInputValue] = useState('');
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState('');
 
    const getTasks = () => {
        return tasks;
    };
    const onSearchInputValueChange = (e) => {
        setSearchInputValue(e.target.value);
    };
    const onSearch = async(e) => {
        const theRequestOpts = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ searchString: searchInputValue })
        };
        const response = await fetch('/api/searchTasks', theRequestOpts);
        const data = await response.json();
        setTasks(data);
    };
    return (
        <InputBox onSearchInputValueChange={onSearchInputValueChange}/>
        <Button title="Search Tasks:" onClick={onSearch}/>
        <TaskResultBox taskResults={getTasks}/>
    )
}

export default SearchTask
```

// TaskTesultBox.js

```
import React from 'react'
function TaskResultBox({taskResults}) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Task Result:</h1>
            <textarea value={taskResults}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TaskResultBox
```

Comment: What is in your `TaskResultBox`, would you please paste it here?

Comment: I've made an answer, see if it helps

Comment: You may find [this blog about reactive programming with react](https://betterprogramming.pub/reactive-programming-with-react-and-rxjs-88d2789e408a) interesting

Answer (score 3):

**`getTasks` is a function that returns a `tasks` object, so to get the return variable, you would need to invoke it**

So change to:

```
<TaskResultBox taskResults={getTasks()}/>  //<-- Invoke it
```

---

But I wonder why do you need a function just to return that variable but not put it directly to the props?

Like so:

```
<TaskResultBox taskResults={tasks}/>
```